# Missing Oracle Database connection Driver when running on an external host

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When running the Java web service I'm building on Local Host, everything runs smoothly, however when I attempt to run the exact same code on a different host, such as on AWS, it fails.
I have narrowed the cause down to the fact that the database connection driver "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" is absent when the application is not hosted locally, which means that the SQL queries are failing to execute for the obvious reason that they aren't being sent anywhere since the connection is failing to open.

How do I build my project such that the driver is included? Everything else should be fine as it runs as expected on localhost, however I can't run the web service locally, it isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the way you are deploying your webservice. I will give you a checklist, so make sure everything is done.

- Insert the oracle jdbc driver inside the libraries folder on your app -- you should consider java jvm version you are running, since your deployment environment may be different from your dev/testing environment;
- 2nd option: insert the oracle jdbc driver inside your container or application server libraries folder;
- Add to your `$CLASSPATH` or `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable the right option for your oracle jdbc driver

Comment: Oddly enough I'd already included it in the project, however option two fixed things.